# Avoiding the need of dynamic casting in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, methods, casting

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person();
        Animal animal = new Animal();

        Object[] objectArray = new Object[2];

        objectArray[0] =  person;
        objectArray[1] =  animal;

        objectArray[0]).setName("Alex");  //dynamic casting needed here
        objectArray[1]).setName("Kitty");

    }
}
```

How do I avoid the need of dynamic casting when passing arrays of Objects as a parameter?

LE:

As suggested by Steve101, I wrote an interface, but it still doesn't resolve the method. Am I doing something wrong?

LE2: Actually it works like Steve101 has suggested.

```
public interface Entity {

        public String properties();
}

public class Person implements Entity{

    public String properties()
    {
        return "properties_person";
    }
}

public class Animal implements Entity{

    public String properties()
    {
        return "properties_animal";
    }
}

public class PropertiesProcessor {
    public static void getPropertiesArray(Entity[] entityArray)
    {
        ArrayList propertiesArray = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<entityArray.length;i++)
        {
            propertiesArray.add(entityArray[i].properties());  //cannot resolve method here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you cant use an interface on both Person and Animal which defines a setName method?

That way the array can be of type 'Mammal' or similar and casting is only required when type specific methods are required.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass

```
Entity[] objectArray = new Entity[2];

objectArray[0].setName("Alex"); // calls Entity.setName(String)
```

However, if it has to be an `Object[]`, then you can only call them methods on `Object` unless you perform a cast.

Comment: If the cast is not static, as you can see the example, it can be either `animal` or `person`, and in the future it might grow, how can it be avoided?

Comment: @Nick you need to use a common interface.  This is what interfaces are for (defining common method for multiple implementations)

Comment: Yes, this is the first time when I use an interface. Not that I have written a lot of Java before... At least it makes sense now, not just a theoretical aspect.